# Why can't I retrieve the data I expect from sqlite database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I created a database on my phone and put some data in it. When I executed the following command:

```
`select * from DailyAffairEntry;`
```

I got **all** items in the table whose name is *DailyAffairEntry*.

`1491033937313|1491033941293|1491033968286|0.5h|0h0m|gsdfsdgsdgqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq|Finished|Daily|no_data
1491034484096|1491034484096|1491034484096|0.5h|0|xvcxc|Ongoing|Daily|no_data
1491034492043|1491034509143|1491034492043|0.5h|0|xcvd|Ongoing|Daily|no_data
1491034495083|1491034499634|1491034517595|0.5h|0h0m|cxvxds|Finished|Daily|no_data
1491041080956|1491041080956|1491041080956|0.5h|0|dddddfsd|Waiting|Daily|no_data`

The first column's name is *StartTime*

But when I execute the following command:
`select * from DailyAffairEntry where StartTime between '10000000000000' and '1500000000000';`

I only got two of them, which are
`1491034484096|1491034484096|1491034484096|0.5h|0|xvcxc|Ongoing|Daily|no_data
1491041080956|1491041080956|1491041080956|0.5h|0|dddddfsd|Waiting|Daily|no_data`

Whereas I expected to get all of them.

Is there any problem with my command? Why can't I get what I want? Please help me.

Comment: i dont think you're supposed to use single quotes on your numbers as these are dates I assume, in which case then you should use the literal numbers, not the string version. Also are you sure that StartTime ist he first column? For the sake of sanity you should probably dump the columns and their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supplying the table specification would have made it simpler to reproduce the issue.

I created the table `CREATE TABLE`DailyAffairTable`(`StartTime`INTEGER,`Field2`INTEGER,`Field3`INTEGER,`Field4`INTEGER,`Field5`INTEGER,`Field6`INTEGER,`Field7`INTEGER,`Field8`INTEGER,`Field9`INTEGER )`

Using the query:
`select * from DailyAffairTable 
where startTime between 1000000000000 and 15000000000000`

And I see all five rows (the DB Browser doesn't copy null fields):
'"1491033937313"    "1491033941293" "1491033968286"
"1491034484096" "141034484096"  "141034484096"
"1491034492043" "1491034509143" "1491034492043"
"1491034495083" "1491034499634" "1491034517595"
"1491033937313" "1491041080956" "1491041080956"
'

So it works for me...

Comment: Fantastic. I've spend the whole day on it.You really save my life.But I am still can't figure out why I have to do so . Any more explanation?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont'. I was trying to reproduce your database. To see what was going on.